# Not able to embed sites in an application in Shopify (X-Frame-Options)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shopify, x-frame-options

I've been working on my first RoR/Shopify-application for the last couple of weeks and it is nearly finished. The only thing I'm having trouble with are the application charges. When a user sees my application in the store he clicks on "Get" and the authentication process is then initialized. The app is being installed and the user can Accept/Decline the charges. If he declines, he is redirected to my app listing in the store.
Now here is my problem. If the user declines the fees my application is still installed and if he clicks on my banner a second time I need to check whether he is paying for it or not. I do it via

```
if (ShopifyAPI::RecurringApplicationCharge.current)
   some logic since the charge is valid
else 
   redirect_to billing_index_path(:shop_url => cur_shop_url)
```

My idea was to make the popup with the charging fees show up once again if the user hasn't paid yet. This doesn't work and I get an error saying that my site was not displayed because the X-Frame-Options are set to DENY. I've already tried to delete the options in my application_controller.rb and also in my application.rb using either

```
Response.headers.delete('X-Frame-Options')
```

and

```
config.action_dispatch.default_headers.delete('X-Frame-Options')
```

respectively. The first time the user installs the app everything seems to work, the embedding, the logic etc. but after he tries it a second time all hell breaks loose. How can I embed all the sites each time a user accesses my application? I read that Shopify's response has a DENY Header by default but I am sure that there must be a solution to this problem. I can't make a user uninstall the app every single time.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I too would like to know the answer to this. It is a hole in the Shopify pattern they have not addressed to my knowledge. I use Sinatra and have the same issue with trying to get the payment confirmation dialog to show a second/third or more time.

Comment: Why don't you add a free very limited plan? this way, you have lots of merchants on board so they can try the magic of your app?

Comment: @alexandresaiz I did it now the way I described below. I added a trial of 7 days so it should be enough. I would do the first app for free but I'm not the one to decide such things ;)

Comment: shopify api: worst dev experience ever

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Shopify ignore 302's to their charge approval forms. The reason being, that your app is embedded in an iframe. The payment confirmation endpoint refuses to be embedded inside an iframe regardless of origin - they don't even whitelist their own site!!

This means you **CANNOT** simply do a form post and 302 on success to the subscription confirmation url, that would be too easy.

You **MUST** write some javascript that will take the confirmation url and perform `window.top.location = confirm_url;`.

You **MUST** break out of the iframe or shopify will also deny you redirect capabilities and you'll be back where you were.

Alternatively, you can open the link in a new window.

I had to convert my 'quick and simple' app to make an Ajax call to submit the subscription information to my server, then do a JS redirect using the resulting confirmation url sent back.

Have to say, Shopify's API is *horrendously* under-documented, and incredibly poorly implemented. At every turn their "API" puts up a roadblock.

Comment: The issues is that Shopify don't allow 302 redirects from embedded apps.  I experienced my app timing out.  It turns out this error appeared in the javascript console

Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://<shop_name>.myshopify.com/admin/charges/<id>/confirm_recurring_application_charge?signature=<signature_hash> does not permit framing.

I followed @Rebs instructions and re-wrote the 302 as a javascript redirect (window.top.location) and it worked fine.

Comment: I produced a screencast demonstrating the problem and reported this issue to Shopify in ticket 2421717 on 27/11/2015, but as of 18/1/2016 they have chosen not to do anything about it.

Comment: @Rebs I had the same issue, I solved by making ajax call to get subscription information. Then redirect to confirmation page using the method you suggested. But now I am unable to go back to iframe scope of the shopify.

Answer (score 1):

Add these below code in config/application.rb file

```
config.action_dispatch.default_headers['P3P'] = 'CP="Not used"'
config.action_dispatch.default_headers.delete('X-Frame-Options')
config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation [really helps](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is by far not the solution I was looking for but oh well. If I see that the charge is not valid I redirect the user to my billing_error_path. There I have a button with a link_to to my shopify-app listing. There he can click on "Get" once again and is then redirected back to my shop and can accept/decline the fees once again. Probably not the best solution but at least it does what I was looking for